# Problem rendering a Wavefront mesh, nothing displays(VBO)

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d-meshes, vbo, obj

I'm having a problem with displaying my wavefront obj file using VBO's My fps counter slows down like there is something being drawn but I cannot see anything. Is it a problem with my loader? Or maybe just a simple bug in my VBO rendering code?

I have checked that I am actually loading the data but maybe it's in the wrong order. I used OpenGL profiler and found nothing specious the texture and the VBO and IBO are in the GPU. I did try two different obj files, one of mine and a random one I found on NASA's site both rendered at the same speed(about 60 fps) with nothing on the screen. If you want any output from OpenGL profiler ask me.

BlockRender.cpp
http://pastebin.com/3KuuWX9H

Renderer.cpp
http://pastebin.com/gDCvi3t7

Relevant snippets of code
http://pastebin.com/rTqRzYXL

Sample wavefront obj file
http://pastebin.com/qVJ55gwn

Comment: Try reversing the triangle winding order, maybe you are not seeing anything because of backface culling

Comment: I disabled backface culling with no success. I'll also try to change my winding order but that shouldn't make a difference with backface culling off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations:

- *First, there's no error checking in the code.*
- The obj loading seems incorrect.

  The vertices are copied into `mesh.vertices` (l. 212-214 in BlockRenderer). Using the DefaultCube, `mesh.vertices` contains 12*3 vertices, and the index buffer 36 ints.

  Problem seems that the indices reference into the original `verts` array and not into `mesh.vertices`. BlockRenderer.cpp l.216ff should IMO read like

  ```
  mesh.indices.push_back(3*i+0); // not faces[i].v[0]
  mesh.indices.push_back(3*i+1); // not faces[i].v[1]
  mesh.indices.push_back(3*i+2); // not faces[i].v[2]
  ```
- However, when using indices, I'd expect the original vertices to stay untouched, and the faces defined by the indices. Then, the vertex buffer must contain 24 floats defining 8 vertices that define the cube's corners. For building the vertex buffer, the code needs to iterate over `verts` and just push the vertices into `mesh.vertices`; the corresponding index buffer then is built using the original code.
- You're sure the mesh is a triangle strip?
- Why not using an [asset loading library](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, I have taken time to add some more OpenGL error checking since I have posted the question. Now on the subject of the obj loading I have implmented your sugestions I think with nothing still loading on the screen. And on the subject of the third part library, I decided to roll my own for the learning experience.

Here is my new post process code:
http://pastebin.com/rnmNFhHW

Comment: Be sure to understand what the code does. Now the indices are such that they would be correct using your original code, but `mesh.vertices` now contains _the first vertex of each face_. This doesn't look like making much sense, huh? Check [an introduction](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html) to the topic.

Comment: Oh ok I understand now, But another question if you don't mind. Don't you need 24 vertices for proper normals to work? Or am i completely wrong there also? Also wouldn't I at least see some garbage displayed if my vertices ore wrong? I'm reading over that introduction now. I'll mark this as the answer when I get done reading.

Comment: Another tidbit of info, I tried using draw arrays instead with my original code and nothing showed either, wouldn't of that for sure displayed something?

Comment: Sorry to spam your StackExchange but even immediate mode doesn't draw anything. http://pastebin.com/AH6QEVus

Comment: Did rendering _ever_ work? Does the code set a color or is this black on black?

Comment: Yes the rendering code worked when I used my own format, i even pulled and old commit on my repo to test that and i got a nice 16x16x16 cube of blocks in my old code. And in my fragment shader i have set the fragment to always be red `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);`

Comment: I got it fixed, Thanks for your help :) It was in my initialization code I disabled all of the special stuff and it worked! Edit: It was my depth testing I enabled.